# django: How to set date and time to server from client

Tags: javascript, django, datetime, django-models

I try to semplify my situation:

I have two PC, **PC1** ("server") is not on the web, instead the **PC2** ("client") can surf on the web (they communicate between each other).

Into **PC1** I have my Django project, DB etc.. while with **PC2** I can access via browser to my project an so on.

I would like to reach this goal:

*PC1 take the date and time from PC 2 automatically and in PC 1 every actions refers to time and date of PC2.*

```
| PC1 (server-side) | <--datetime--- | PC2 (client-side) |<----- datetime from web
```

Actually I can take the client datetime with some js:

**datetime.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
    function myTimer() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    var strDate = myDate.getFullYear()+ "-" +(myDate.getMonth()+1)+ "-" +myDate.getDate();
    var strTime = myDate.getHours()+ ":" + myDate.getMinutes() +":" + myDate.getSeconds();

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = myDate.toLocaleString();

}       


})
```

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class ProvaTime(models.Model):
    somewords = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    myauthor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()   # how tell it to pick js timedate?



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProvaTime, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ProvaTime

class ProvaTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model =  ProvaTime
        fields = ('somewords',)
```

**views.py**

```
def testime(request):

    elements =ProvaTime.objects.filter().order_by('-created_date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProvaTimeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.author = request.user
            obj.save()
    else:
        form = ProvaTimeForm()

    return render(request, 'provapp/testime.html', {'form': form, 'elements': elements})

def myviewtomodel(request): # how to do?
```

**provapp/testime.html**

```
<form action="/testime/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="LIST" />
</form>


  <br />
  <br />        

                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr class="info">
                            <td width="15%" align="center">SOMETHING WORDS</td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> CREATION DATETIME </td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> AUTHOR </td>
                            <td>


                            </td>
                            {% for stuff in elements %}
                                <div class="stuff">
                                    <tr>

                                    <td>{{stuff.somewords}}</td> 
                                    <td>{{stuff.created_date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{stuff.myauthor}}</td>
                                </div>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

**How can I send JS datetime to models.py?**

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the javascript date to your models explicitly.

`model.created_date = date_from_javascript`

Since you have set the default value for `created_date` as `timezone.now` it will use the server's timezone when nothing is passed to it.

ex.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myview/',
    data: {'javascript_date' : javascript_date},
    method: 'post',
    ....
});
```

in your django view:

```
def MyView(request):
    javascript_date = request.POST['javascript_date']
    m = MyModel(created_at=javascript_date)
    m.save()
```

Comment: How can I define `date_from_javascript`?

Comment: You can pass it to your django view through javascript.

Comment: Is there a django function that picks the datetime from the client?

Comment: @DigitalDouble: I'm on difficulties to figure out your variables written here... Might you be a little bit more detailed, please?

Comment: e.g. `m = MyModel(created_at=javascript_date)    m.save()`  and how I call m in models.py... e.g. like: `m=models.DateTimeField()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not save client time directly in the database. Because while there is multiple clients with different timezone, then one client will see wrong time as that was created in separate timezone. I will suggest you to use `session` to save the offset value (Or database)and use it for displaying data.

Now lets make an ajax request in home page or another page which will send the offset data to the server from browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var now = new Date()
    var value = now.getTimezoneOffset()

    $.ajax({
        url: "your-url",
        type: "post", // or "get"
        data: value,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }});

});
```

add an extra field to model to save that offset. And a property method which will later calculate user's local time.

```
class ProvaTime(models.Model):
    ....
    tz_offset = models.DecimalField(default=Decimal('0.0'),max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)

    @property
    def get_local_time(self):
        return create_time - datetime.timedelta(tz_offset)
```

and ajax the view

```
import json
def post(request):
  if request.POST():
      data = {}
      try:
         get_value= request.body
         prova_times = ProvaTime.objects.filter(myauthor=request.user)
         if prova_times.exists():
             for prova_time in prova_times:
                 prova_time.tz_offset = get_value
                 prova_time.save()
         data['success'] = 'Success'
         return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
      except Exception as e:
         data['error'] = e
         return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Now displaying the data:

```
def myviewtomodel(request):
    context = dict()
    context['elements'] = ProvaTime.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context,
        content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

Showing time in template(using `get_local_time`).

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tr class="info">
                            <td width="15%" align="center">SOMETHING WORDS</td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> CREATION DATETIME </td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"> AUTHOR </td>
                            <td>


                            </td>
                            {% for stuff in elements %}
                                <div class="stuff">
                                    <tr>

                                    <td>{{stuff.somewords}}</td> 
                                    <td>{{stuff.get_local_time}}</td>
                                    <td>{{stuff.myauthor}}</td>
                                </div>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: No problem about client.. because there will be only one *PC2* connected to *PC1*.. I have to save some data and it is necessary that the saved data are stored in DB with client datetime because the PC1 must not surf on the web so its datetime has to set with client time...

Comment: Then just store the offset in database and use it when you are displaying the time :)

Comment: but how tell to MyModel to pick this datetime? Actually it returns: 'module' object has no attribute 'myview'